# Can the effect of a link be restored after relocation of the comment containing it into the body of an answer by the commentator?

Tags: support

I recently moved a conclusive comment (made by myself) on an OP's question into the body of my answer to it.  In that process, the underlining and color-coding that characterize a link was (probably by an automated process) removed from the relocated verbiage.  As an opening paragraph in the linked material provides a key element in the answer, is there any way that its functionality as a link can be restored?

Comment: I don't really understand what the setting is here. When you say you "moved" or "relocated" the comment,, what exactly are you doing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You seem to be referring to [this edit](https://physics.stackexchange.com/revisions/672960/7), in which a link to [this url from a deleted comment](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/265788031_A_New_Approach_to_Cosmological_Bulk_Viscositye) has been rendered as `researchgate.net/publication/…`.

Copy-paste does not, in general, pick up links, formatting, and the like.  Click the "edit" button under this answer to see what your "source text" should look like to produce the link you want. Or click the question mark at the top-right of the editor window, which gives an in-place summary of the [more comprehensive editing help](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/editing-help).

Comment: Thanks, sounds good; just leaving this advice up to apply it after running some errands.